Angular16 MongoDB Multiple Parameters on Http Post
I need to pass two parameters to my end point, along with the request so that would make it three and only two are allowed per my http post request.  I tried the HttpParams but that does not work in my case.  The situation is when product is chosen a size must be chosen as well.  It works when I add url plus end point and append the Id. I then add Id to my end point, I have already tested it, product is added to cart. There are different sizes for each product so a size must me chosen. Once I get the issue with the parameter figured out I will update the item by Id this is the reason I need both parameters.  I can't append the size and Id I will get an error.
I Need figure out the best approach to get both.  Everything I had tried does not work.
Can someone point me in the right direction: Code snippet below:
cart Service:
     addProductToCart(product:Product, _id:String, size:String):Observable<Product>{


     return this.http.post<Product>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/addtocart' + _id, 
     {product})

   }

api:
        router.post('/getProducts/addtocart:_id',   async(req, res)=> {
      .......
        }) //this works

update service:
         UpdateCart(product:Product, _id:String, size:String):Observable<Product>{

          alert("Service update cart")


       return this.http.post<Product>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/updatecart/' + _id + 
        size, {product})


        }

api end point:
        router.post('/getProducts/updatecart/:_id/:size', async(req,res)=>{  
 
        const _id = req.params.id;
        const size = req.params.size;

       }); //The above does not work gives me an error
  
    


you can also send the id and size in post body

You are missing one / when sending request, should be return this.http.post<Product>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/updatecart/' + _id + '/' + size, {product})

Wow thanks just a formatting issue. This worked for what  I was trying to accomplish.  This the accepted answer.    I'm curious as to how I could have done it with post body. Thank you so much.

A few things here,
when you call the endpoint you should try to use the following to build your endpoint
this.http.post<Product>(`${this.rootUrl}/getProducts/addToCart/${id}/${size}`, {product})

This helps with readability and could help with debugging if something is wrong with the endpoint itself.
Your API endpoint(express code I assume) does seem mostly correct except that you are trying to access id instead of _id here is a refined version for you
router.post('/getProducts/updatecart/:_id/:size', async (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params._id;
  const size = req.params.size;
});

You can now pass through the data to your service level code and it should function correctly.
